# Nginx regular expression on map

Tags: regex, dictionary, nginx

Not an expert on regexs,

working on a nginx project, and we are looking for a way to map the first two (2) directories levels of a uri

```
map $uri $my_uri {
                ~^(?<base_uri>.*)/[^/]+$   $base_uri; 
                default                    $uri;
        }
```

So far this code return the base_uri without the domain/server or any filenames

But I need this original request :

http://example.com/level1/level2/file.ext

http://example.com/level1/level2/level3/file.ext

http://example.com/level1/level2/level3/level4/[...more levels...]/file.ext

to return only the first 2 levels, regex should return

/level1/level2

Please note:

1. sub-folders (lavel1, lavel2) will be dynamic folder names, not static.
2. nginx's $url variable does not include protocol/server/port from the original request. so regex is performed against /level1/level2/level3/[...]/file.ext

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Try: `~^(?<base_uri>/[^/]+/[^/]+)/`

Comment: thank you! that did the trick!